# How to show a continuous function is bounded when the domain is compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$K$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I have to show that $K$ is compact if and only if every continuous function $f: K \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded.
I know that if $f$ is continuous and $K$ is compact then $f$ is uniformly continuous. Does it mean the function is bounded ? I have no idea how to connect compact and continuity.

Comment: Look what compact means, and from a corollary from Alfhors, "A continuous real-valued function on a compact set has a minimum and maximum." Hint I believe the Heine-Borel property would work here.

Comment: It is almost immediate from the definition. The open cover $f^{-1} ( (n,n+1) )$ has a finite subcover.

Answer (score 1):

Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be nonempty.

(If $K$ is compact, then for each continuous function $f: K \to \mathbb{R}$, $f (K)$ is bounded.) First, you can show that a continuous image of a compact set is compact. This is straightforward: consider an arbitrary open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $f (K)$. Since $f$ is continuous, the collection $\{f^{-1} (U) | U \in \mathcal{U}\}$ constitutes an open cover of $K$. Since $K$ is compact, there is a finite open subcover $\{f^{-1} (U_1), \dots, f^{-1} (U_n)\}$ of $K$. Then $\{U_1, \dots, U_n\} \subseteq \mathcal{U}$ constitutes a finite open subcover of $f (X)$. Conclude by observing that $f (K) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, being compact, must be bounded: if not, the open cover $\{f (K) \cap (y - 1, y + 1) | y \in f (K)\}$ of $f (K)$ would have no finite subcover, for instance.

(If for each continuous function $f: K \to \mathbb{R}$, $f (K)$ is bounded, then $K$ is compact.) By Heine-Borel, it is equivalent to show that $K$ is closed and bounded in the Euclidean metric, which we denote by $d$.

1. ($K$ is closed.) Suppose not. Then $K$ does not contain one of its limit points $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the continuous function $f_1: K \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f_1 (x) = \frac{1}{d (x, x_0)}$. You can easily show that $f_1 (K)$ is unbounded. So, $K$ must be closed.
2. ($K$ is bounded.) The function $f_2: K \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_2 (x) = d (x, 0)$ is continuous. If $f_2 (K)$ is bounded, then there exists some $L \ge 0$ such that $f_2 (x) \le L$ for each $x \in K$. Using the Triangle Inequality, it follows that $d (x_1, x_2) \le d (x_1, 0) + d (0, x_2) = f_2 (x_1) + f_2 (x_2) \le L + L = 2 L$ for any $x_1, x_2 \in K$. This shows $K$ is bounded, as desired.